# How to create a MFC dialog with a progress bar in a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, dialog, progress-bar

My application may take a while to connect to a database. This connection is made with a single library function call, i.e. I cannot put progress updates in there and make callbacks or something similar.

My idea was to create a dialog with a progress bar in a separate thread before connecting to the DB. This dialog will continually change the progress status with `CProgressCtrl::StepIt()` so the user sees something happening.
After that dialog is set up and doing its thing I want to call the DB connection function from the main thread.
After the connection function completed, I want to stop the progress bar thread.

Let me paint a picture:

```
CMyApp::       ProgressThread
InitInstance()      .
    |               .
    |               .
    +-Create Dialog-+
    |               |
    |             Animate
 Connect          Progress
    to             Bar
    DB              |
    |               |
    +-Destroy Dlg---+
    |               .
    |               .
```

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Maybe the whole thing would work using timers, too. Would probably be much simpler but I couldn't get that to work either.

1. I am aware of `CProgressCtrl::SetMarquee()` which might do exactly what I need but I can't use it because the application does not have Unicode support.
2. I could move the db connection call into a separate thread but that way it looks like a lot of changes to the code and extra handling of connection errors.

**Update 2**
I got it working the way AlexEzh and Javier De Pedro suggested: Put the DB stuf into its own thread.
initially I had concerns about how error handling could be done but it's actually quite similar to how it was before.

1. In the main thread I create a struct with connection parameters, result flag and thread-running-flag. The latter is initially set to `true`.
2. I create a thread and pass that struct as parameter.
3. I create a dialog that displays a progress bar in the main thread.
4. Also in the main thread there is a loop that runs while the thread-running-flag is set. It calls `CMyDialog::Animate()` which calls `CProgressCtrl::StepIt()` and then `Sleep()`s a bit.
5. The thread executes the db-connection code and sets the running-flag to `false` when done.
6. When the main thread exits the loop it can handle errors exactly as it did before.

**Disadvantage:** Moving the mouse over the window doesn't work. It's invisible. Thus no cancel-button or other interactive dialog elements can be used. I can live with that, however.

Since you liked the diagram, here is how it now looks like:

```
CMyApp::        WorkerThread
InitInstance()      .
    |               .
    |               .
Create Dialog       .
    |               .
    +-Start Thread--+
    |               |
    |             Connect
 Animate            to
 Progress           DB
   Bar              |
    |               |
    +-Thread Ends---+
    |               .
 Destroy Dlg        .
    |               .
```

Comment: You can call SetMarquee() in an ANSI application, but it won't help you since the timer that animates the progress bar is called on the main thread also

Comment: In my afxcmn.h it looks like this:
**
if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501) && defined(UNICODE) \n
BOOL SetMarquee(_In_ BOOL fMarqueeMode, _In_ int nInterval); \n
#endif // _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501 && defined(UNICODE) \n
**
And that's why I cannot call it.

Comment: a flock in the headers, copy that code (it just sends a message) and use it.

Comment: I tried it in a separate test project now: All of the following conditions must be met for the marquee to work: 1. Enable "Marquee" in resource properties (PBS_MARQUEE). 2. Send the message PBM_SETMARQUEE to the control. 3. Compile with Unicode support.

Comment: MFC are not thread safety...it is not safe to pass pointers and access them from other threads.
As I told you the way to do it is moving the DB connection to the worker thread and letting the UI to update the controls. If you really need to have the DB connection in the ui thread I would try this:
1 - Create the progress bar in the progress bar in the ui thread (for instance in the OnInitDialog method of the dialog).
2 - Pass a handle (HWND) of the progress bar to the worker thread.
3 - Add the progress bar directly using Win32 ie SendMessage and PBM_STEPIT.

Comment: In step 3 I meant Access the progress bar instead of Add.

Comment: you can get rid of this disadvantage by using a modal dialog and a timer.
In the OnInitDialog start the thread and set the timer. In the OnTimer call StepIt to update the progress.
But make sure you control all the possible ways to close the dialog either to don't let the user or stop the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would still be safer to move the DB connection logic to the separate thread. With DB on the dialog thread, you will be able to repaint the progress bar but not other controls in the dialog.

Comment: I can repaint the whole dialog by calling RedrawWindow(). If I don't do that, only the progress bar is animated.

Answer (score 7):

I hope [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/win32splash.aspx) article about creating own-thread splash screen with progress bar could be helpful. I wrote it while solving the problem with thread locking at MFC message queue level.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create worker thread using [`AfxBeginThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e(VS.80).aspx).
2. In that thread Create a [`CProgressCtrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sys15k39(VS.80).aspx) and call [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86dk8abh(VS.80).aspx), pass the dialog as the parent of the CProgressCtrl, use the marquee style for the progress control.
3. In the Thread create a message waiting loop:

   MSG msg;
   while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
   {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }
4. The message loop need to check a global flag to see if to exit the loop.

Comment: @Kirill This works for me, on my project, what exactly doesn't suppose to work?

Comment: MFC thread could be deadlocked in Create function. To avoid that you should use non-MFC threads.

Comment: @Kirill deadlock on what? what are the two resource that lock each other?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `SendMessage` with `PBM_SETMARQUEE` instead of `SetMarquee`. I've never tried myself but it should work.

In my opinion the easiest way to achive what you want to do is making both the ProgressBar and DB connection in the ui thread and using OnTimer to call `StepIt` in the progress bar. 
You can also create the progress bar in the ui thread and use a custom message for the working thread to modify the progress status.

Anyway,  I agree with AlexEzh that the best way to do it is making the whole non-UI work in the working thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create a member variable as

```
CProgressCtrl m_progress;
```

add the `m_progress` in `DDX_Control` in `DoDataExcchange` with the progress bar ID

add the following code under Button click function.

```
m_progress.setRange(0,100);
m_progress.SetPos(1);
```

Comment: This is only very basic information which was neither asked for nor does is address the multi-thread problem.