# Open a MFC dialog in a std::thread

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, stdthread

I would like to show a dialog to inform the user that the application is busy. To avoid blocking of the main thread, I was thinking to use a std::thread to show the dialog. Consider the following code:

```
InProcDlg inProcess;
std::thread t([ &inProcess ] {      
    inProcess.DoModal();
    delete inProcess;
});
// wait till process has finished 
::PostMessage(inProcess.m_hWnd, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);
if (t.joinable()){
    t.join();
}
```

InProcDlg.cpp

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(InProcDlg, CDialogEx)
  ...
  ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 1, &InProcDlg::close)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT InProcDlg::close(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam, lParam);
  EndDialog(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Running this code the dialog is shown properly. The dialog is also closed, but the main dialog is not shown, the application hangs in `CreateRunDlgIndirect()`. Trying to step in, while setting some breakpoints the main dialog is shown properly back again. Very strange. I would be very happy for any advices where I have to dive deeper in.

In the next step I would also like to show the process to the user, by sending an integer indicating the current state of process.

```
int *percent;
::PostMessage(inProcess.m_hWnd, WM_USER + 2, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(percent));
```

How I can gain evidence that the dialog is already existing, before sending or posting a message?
I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669017/how-to-create-a-mfc-dialog-with-a-progress-bar-in-a-separate-thread

Comment: Does `delete inProcess;` even compile? In any case, drop it - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's better, and usually easier, to do it the other way round - show the dialog on the main UI thread, run busy processing on a worker thread.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your suggestions. Actually, I had considered this approach (show the dialog on the main UI thread, run busy processing on a worker thread) in the beginning but affright of all the message handling. But also with my current approach I have to take care of the message handling, anyhow. I will rewrite my code, by implementing your suggested way.

Comment: You cannot safely spread a window hierarchy across multiple threads (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)). Leaving that aside, `WM_USER` belongs to the window class implementation. In this particular case, some dialog window class. If you want to send application private messages, you need to use the `WM_APP + x` range of messages.

Comment: @IInspectable: The link warns specifically about cross-process hierarachies, and notes that cross-thread window hierarchies are simpler because cross-thread variable sharing is easier and no messages are filtered.

Comment: @MSalters: You've got this backwards. The article never says, that things get easier, when both threads are owned by the same process. The blog entry says, that crossing process boundaries makes things harder. Regardless, this user is trying to solve a problem for which there is no solution. Using MFC means giving up the level of control you need to safely implement a cross-thread window hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to do that:

**Modeless dialog**

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC

**User thread (UI thread)**

Creating a brother to the main UI thread (CWinApp) by using CWinThread. Most important is to assign CWinThread::m_pMainWnd member, with a pointer to a Dialog. If the dialog is Modal you return FALSE right after the call to DoModal, and return TRUE for Modeless.

```
class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd {
    // pointer to thread
    CWinThread* m_pUserThread;
}
```

start thread

```
m_pUserThread = AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CUserThread), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED );
m_pUserThread->m_bAutoDelete = TRUE;
m_pUserThread->ResumeThread();
```

headr file**

```
class CUserThread : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CUserThread)
public:
    CUserThread();

    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CUserThread)
    public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

protected:
    virtual ~CUserThread();
    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CUserThread)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
private:
    CUserMsg* m_pDlg;
}
```

source file

```
#define DO_MODAL
BOOL CUserThread::InitInstance()
{

    #ifdef DO_MODAL
    // create and assign Modeless dialog
    CUserMsg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &m_pDlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
    return FALSE;
    #endif

    #ifdnef DO_MODAL
    // create and assign Modal dialog
    m_pDlg = new CUserMsg();
    m_pDlg->Create( IDD_USER_DLG, AfxGetMainWnd() );
    m_pMainWnd = m_pDlg;
    return TRUE;
    #endif
}

int CUserThread::ExitInstance()
{
    // check for null
    m_pDlg->SendMessage( WM_CLOSE ) ;
    delete m_pDlg;

    return CWinThread::ExitInstance();
}
```

to terminate the thread

```
// post quit message to thread
m_pUserThread->PostThreadMessage(WM_QUIT,0,0);

// wait until thread termineates
::WaitForSingleObject(m_pUserThread->m_hThread,INFINITE);
```

For both ways I would highly recommend making the dialog as a top most window:

```
BOOL CLicenseGenDlg::OnInitDialog() {
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    SetWindowPos( &wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | WS_EX_TOPMOST );
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this won't work as explained in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407418/open-a-mfc-dialog-in-a-stdthread?noredirect=1#comment70025977_41407418).